# RadListView cannot read property 'picture' of undefined (Android)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am using RadListView and have a list of images that is using loadOnDemand to load more. Every once in a while I receive a nasty error on Android that says `Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined`, and it will sort of freeze the whole app for a little while.

It's frustrating because I keep thinking I fix it when it doesn't happen for a while, but then it will come back randomly. I thought a complete project refactoring might fix the problem, but it didn't.

I created a sample project that has the problem. https://github.com/keerl/radlistview-bug.

I also created a Playground for it: https://play.nativescript.org/?id=H7lJuH&template=play-ng&v=3

I also recorded a video of the problem happening. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EGvw8REek8. The problem is very random, sometimes it will never trigger (which makes me think I fixed it), then randomly hours later start happening again. Only happens on Android. I've tried using plugins for image caching (WebImage) thinking that the image loading was causing the problem and maybe a placeholder would help, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?id=H7lJuH&template=play-ng&v=4) for you. You were notifying too early to the list that `notifyPullToRefreshFinished`.

You should only inform only when data is loaded. E.g.

```
loadProducts(PullToRefreshInitiated: boolean) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            http.getJSON("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=25&inc=picture").then((r) => {
                this.users$.push(r.results);
                if (PullToRefreshInitiated) {
                    this.listView.notifyPullToRefreshFinished();
                }
                // Load a max of 50 items and then force a pull-to-refresh to get more data.
                if (this.users$.length > 50) {
                    resolve(true);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            }, (e) => {
                console.log(e)
            });
        });
    }
```

P.S. Two more suggestions that I have personally implemented in a similar environment.

1. Use image [cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-web-image-cache).
2. Use [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) in  e.g. `<Image *ngIf="item" [src]="item.picture.medium"></Image>`, you can use a Label for else block of you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran your updated Playground and I received the "Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined" right away still. I tried using the `*ngIf="item"` on the Image but now I can't scroll at all, it seems to only load 6 images.

Comment: When you are trying *ngIf, you should put Image inside a stacklayout as empty image tag ( in case item is undefine) will give you error

Comment: Doesn't seen to be working. I'm getting "No suitable views found in list template!" error now. Tried Image inside StackLayout and an else statement, no luck.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mentioned in case of ‘item’ undefined because of *ngIf , ng-template will not render and you will get No suitable view error. That is why I suggested either create a component and in that component have that Image or use elsebock of *ngIf

Comment: Ok, I seem to have it working sorta. See the updated [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?id=H7lJuH&template=play-ng&v=5). It works great on the initial app launch, but when I make a change in playground and it re-syncs to my phone everything freezes up and can't really scroll.

Comment: Could be some other issue, I tried with your playground and it is working fine on ios.

Comment: Does it freeze for you when you make a change on Android?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189559/discussion-between-narendra-mongiya-and-keerl).